# How to use resultset to output SQL SUM Statement?

Tags: java, sql, resultset

Aim: I would like to print line the output of the below SQL statment. Normally I use `rs.getString("rowname")` however SUM doesn't specify a COLUMN, so I am a little stumped on how this can be done.

```
SELECT SUM(HOURS) FROM RESOURCE WHERE DATE = '02/08/2013'; --Actual SQL Query as used below

ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(HOURS) FROM RESOURCE WHERE DATE = '02/08/2013';");

            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td>" + rs.get + "</td>");
            out.println("</tr>");            
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
rs.getLong(1);
```

**Note**

avoid mixing code and view

Answer (score 1):

On top of @JigarJoshi's answer, another way to get what you want is to use an `Alias`.

```
SELECT SUM(HOURS) AS "SUM_HOURS" FROM RESOURCE WHERE DATE = '02/08/2013';
```

And then use,

```
rs.getString(SUM_HOURS);
```